# display the first image from a google image search for places

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I wanted to get the first image returned from an image search for the place in question and then assign that as the src for an image tag.

I looked up the API for Google Image search which is depricated, and was having some issues reading the new Custom Search API at https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results#Image_Query_Parameter_Definitions and search for "Image Search Query"

When i was trying to create a sample link such as: http://www.google.com/cse?searchtype=image&start=0&num=1&q=monkey&as_filetype=png&client=google-csbe&output=xml_no_dtd&cx=00255077836266642015:u-scht7a-8i i noticed this has to be placed inside of something and was thinkking to have it inside of a jquery

```
$.ajax("http://www.google.com/cse?searchtype=image&start=0&num=1&q=monkey&as_filetype=png&client=google-csbe&output=xml_no_dtd&cx=00255077836266642015:u-scht7a-8i", function(){console.log(arguments);});
```

but i would get a cross domain error when doing it from the javascript console.  Is there something i am needing to make this acceptable?

Overall my goal is to be able to link elsewhere the images so they would not be on my server for the time being.

**The general concept i want to do is to get the URL for the first image of a google image search given keywords such as an address, bar, bowling alley, etc, etc**

Comment: Maybe you should do it with PHP, file_get_contents or curl.. ?

Comment: Also this won't output anything ttp://www.google.com/cse?searchtype=image&start=0&num=1&q=monkey&as_filetype=png&client=google-csbe&output=xml_no_dtd&cx=00255077836266642015:u-scht7a-8i

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Ill check to see what file_get_contents returns

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet I dont think that returns anything

Comment: Neither does in browser, are you sure the url is right?

Comment: i changed the cx=????   data, and the XMP file returned is 403.
`http://www.google.com/cse?searchtype=image&start=0&num=1&q=monkey&as_filetype=png&client=google-csbe&output=xml_no_dtd&cx=008229370933731661924:ymbxzgdowq0`

Comment: So we need a working url in order to try to help you..

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet is there an alternate option to doing this via google cse?  I wasnt sure if a hack could be to scrape data from a hidden frame